# Normality of sequence

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I am using R, If I have a sequence of 1:100 and if I try to determine the normality of this data, I get this result, The result suggests that the data is not normal.

```
shapiro.test(1:100)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  1:100
W = 0.95472, p-value = 0.001722
```

However, if do a plot like this:

```
plot(dnorm(1:100, mean(1:100), sd(1:100)))
```

I find a plot which is quite normal,So now I am confused as the plot seems to be perfectly normal but the test says otherwise. Can someone help me to understand this? I am sure I am mistaken by some concept of statistics but I am unable to figure out what I am missing? Thanks

Comment: `dnorm(1:100, mean(1:100), sd(1:100))` may not be drawing what you may think.  It is just the peak of a normal density with mean $50.5$ and standard deviation about $288.8$, and tells you nothing about the non-normality of a uniformly distributed random variable.  Instead perhaps try `qqnorm(1:100)` and note you do not get anything close to the straight line you might get with normally distributed data such as `qqnorm(rnorm(1000))`

Comment: @Henry, Thanks, I understood. I was trying to relate two complete different things and I was totally confused between them. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at two completely unrelated things. Yes, looking at *the normal density evaluated at 1, ..., 100* (and matched for mean and variance) will look normal, because it *is*. But to assess whether the original data are normal or not, you need to look at the original data, not a normal transformation of the normal data.

Look at it this way: plotting the *exponential* density evaluated at 1, ..., 100 (matched for the mean) will look exponential - but that of course does not mean that the original data are exponential. And the same for any other distribution.

Instead, look at `hist(1:100)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for answer, I understood what you said. So when we run `dnorm` , it means we are looking at transformed data, not the original data. so one can say that 1:100 is not normal if we don't look at any transformation.